# Prove that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}\sin{(\frac{\pi}{x})}$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I have to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)}$ does not exist.

**My idea:** from the definition of function limit, if I found $x_n\to\infty$ and $y_n\to\infty$ and $x_n,y_n\neq 0$ such that $\frac{1}{x_n}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{x_n}\right)}\to l_1$ and $\frac{1}{y_n}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{y_n}\right)}\to l_2$ with $l_1\neq l_2$ then I have proved the limit does not exist.

I have taken: $x_n=\frac{1}{2n}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{1/2+2n}$ and so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{x_n}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2n\sin{(2\pi n)}=0=l_1\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{y_n}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{y_n}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/2+2n)\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)}=\infty=l_2$$

Since $l_1\neq l_2$ then the limit does not exist.

**Question:** my work is right?

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But why for wolfram $l_1$ is indeterminate? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n-%3Einf+%282+n%29sin%282+pi+n%29

Comment: @pawel I think WA assumes the variable $n$ is a real value, in which case the limit is indeed indeterminate. But if $n$ is an integer, then the limit is $0$. This is what is meant when Wolfram Alpha says: "Assuming limit refers to a continuous limit | Use the discrete instead". If you click on "discrete", you get: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n-%3Einf+%282+n%29sin%282+pi+n%29&assumption=%22LimitHead%22+-%3E+%7B%22Discrete%22%7D

Comment: @5xum In my case $n$ is integer since I am using the sequential definition of limit, am I right?

Comment: $l_1=0$ is correct.

Comment: @pawel Yes you are right. The limit $l_1$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your attempt is correct.

Your confusion when using Wolfram Alpha stems from the fact that WA assumes the variable $n$ is "continuous", i.e. it can take any real value. In that case,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n\sin(2\pi n)$$ does not exist.

However, if $n$ is an integer, then the limit exists and is $0$.

---

Note that Wolfram Alpha directly explains this:

[image: Explanation]

After you click "discrete" in the image above, you get the result you were looking for:

[image: Correct result]

which you can also get on [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20n-%3Einf%20%282%20n%29sin%282%20pi%20n%29&assumption=%22LimitHead%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Discrete%22%7D).